# Trying to understand TranslationInView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipangesturerecognizer

In my UITableViewCell subclass I add a pan gesture and in `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` method I  checked `self.frame.origin.x` and `self.frame.origin.y` both are `0.000000 and 0.000000`and after applying `TranslationInView` `CGPoint translation = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:[self superview]];` I am getting `x=-4.000000 and y=0.000000`

How `TranslationInView` work, I am trying to wrap my head around it, when I am getting the correct location of cell 0.0 and 0.0 because the first cell will have 0.0 and 0.0, why I need `TranslationInView`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TranslationInView is a method of UIPanGestureRecognizer and it tells you how far the touch moved since it was last reset. It resets when the touch goes down or if you reset it yourself.

For example

```
- (void) pan: (UIPanGestureRecognizer *) recognizer
{
 if ((recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)||(recognizer.state ==    UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)) {
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self];
    }
}
```

The CGPoint traslation gets increased/decreased the distance that the gesture has moved.